# Cannot assign roles to member even if all permissions are met

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to assign someone a role however it fails due to "Missing Access"

```
method: 'put',
path: '/guilds/GUILDIDHERE/members/MEMBERIDHERE/roles/ROLE IM TRYING TO ASSIGN',
code: 50001,
httpStatus: 403,
```

This is the code I used

```
const role = await guild.roles.fetch("ROLEID HERE");

mention.roles.add(role);
```

My bot has administrator permissions

My bots role is above the role I'm trying to assign

The member who I'm trying to assign the role to has no other roles!

Comment: Try logging the roles name and making sure its the role you meant to give.

Comment: I think you have not coded properly, you may send the code here.